# Why do I get a undefined error on this variable?

Tags: jquery

Can anyone see what is wrong with this bit of jquery code?  I get an **undefined** error message on the variable **reqButEmpty** and consequently it does not run correctly.  THank you in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnCatchReqFlds").on('click', function(){
        alert('made it to this one also');
        var peaches ="hi peaches";
        var reqButEmpty = $('fieldset:visible').find('input[class*="-required"]').filter(function() 
            {
                    alert(peaches);
                    alert('second area 1a');
                    alert(reqButEmpty);
                    return $.trim($(this).val()) === "";
            });
                alert('second area 1b');
                    if(reqButEmpty.length>0)
                    {
                        alert("go here ok");
                        alert(this.length);
                        reqButEmpty.each(function() {
                            $('#hldErrMsg').append("Please fill in the " + this.name + "<br />"); 
                        });
                    }
                    return !reqButEmpty.length;
                });
        });
```

**The html**:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <div id="holdErrMsg"></div>
    <fieldset id="mainSection" name="mainSection">
                <legend style="color:blue; font-weight:bold">Project Overview Section</legend>

                <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 33px; width: 178px;">Name</td>
                        <td style="height: 33px"><input  id="1125" name="1125" class="1125-required" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 33px; width: 178px;">Email</td>
                        <td style="height: 33px"><input id="1026" name="1026" class="1026-required" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 178px">Product Title</td>
                        <td><input  id="1089" name="1089" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 178px">Product Type</td>
                        <td><select id="1169" name="1169">
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                        <option value="Cars">Cars</option>
                        <option value="Boats">Boats</option>
                        <option value="Planes">Planes</option>
                        </select></td>
                    </tr>
                                        <tr><td>
                                        <button id="btnCatchReqFlds" type="button" name="btn">Check Required Fields</button>
                                        </td></tr>
                                    </table>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset id="section-11" name="section-11">
                <legend style="color:fuchsia; font-weight:bold">Car Details Section</legend>

                <table cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px; height: 35px"><label>Size:*</label></td>
                        <td style="height: 35px"><input id="1245" class="1245-required" name="1245" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 35px; width: 334px">Color:*</td>
                        <td style="height: 35px">
                        <select id="1433" class="1433-required" name="1433">
                <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
                        <option value="Blank">Blank</option>
                        <option value="Green">Green</option>
            </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px">Description:</td>
                        <td>
                        <textarea id="1290" name="1290" rows="2" style="width: 433px"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                            </fieldset>

            <fieldset id="section-12" name="section-12">
                <legend style="color:fuchsia; font-weight:bold">Plane Details Section</legend>

                <table cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px; height: 35px"><label>Size:</label></td>
                        <td style="height: 35px"><input id="1245" name="1245" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 35px; width: 334px">Color*:</td>
                        <td style="height: 35px">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="1433[]" id="1433[]" value"Orange" class="1433[]-required"/>Orange
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="1433[]" id="1433[]" value"Blue" class="1433[]-required"/>Blue
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="1433[]" id="1433[]" value"Green" class="1433[]-required"/>Green
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px">Description:</td>
                        <td>
                        <textarea id="1290" name="1290" rows="2" style="width: 433px"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="section-13" name="section-13">
                <legend style="color:fuchsia; font-weight:bold">Boat Details Section</legend>

                <table cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px; height: 35px"><label>Size:</label></td>
                        <td style="height: 35px"><input id="1245" name="1245" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 35px; width: 334px">Color:*</td>
                        <td style="height: 35px">
                                                <input type="radio" name="1834" id="1834" value="None" class="valuetext" class="1834-required">None
                                                <input type="radio" name="1834" id="1834" value="All" class="valuetext" class="1834-required">All
                       </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px">Description:</td>
                        <td>
                        <textarea id="1290" name="1290" rows="2" style="width: 433px"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                            </fieldset><br>
<fieldset id="section-1011" name="section-1011">
                <legend style="color:green; font-weight:bold">Misc Info Section</legend>

                <table cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px; height: 35px"><label>Size:</label></td>
                        <td style="height: 35px"><input id="1301" name="1301" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 35px; width: 334px">Color:</td>
                        <td style="height: 35px">
                        <select id="1302" name="1302">
                <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
                        <option value="Blank">Blank</option>
                        <option value="Green">Green</option>
            </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px">Description:</td>
                        <td>
                        <textarea id="1303" name="1303" rows="2" style="width: 433px"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                            </fieldset>


</form>​
```

**jquery code**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('fieldset#section-11,fieldset#section-12,fieldset#section-13').hide(); 
            });//end of close all fieldsets


            $(document).ready(function() {
                var projType = new Array(
                        {value : 'Cars', sect_id : 'fieldset#section-11'},
                        {value : 'Planes', sect_id : 'fieldset#section-12'},
                        {value : 'Boats', sect_id : 'fieldset#section-13'}
                    ); //end of projType array

            $("select#1169").on('change',function () {
                var dropDownVal = $(this).val();
                var sect_id ="";
                    $(projType).each(function() {
                        $(this.sect_id).hide(); //hide all section each time you run thru here
                            if(this.value == dropDownVal) 
                                {
                                    $(this.sect_id).show();
                                }
                    });
            });
            });
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnCatchReqFlds").on('click', function(){
        console.log('inside onclick of button');
        var peaches ="hi peaches";
        var reqButEmpty = $('fieldset:visible').find('input[class*="-required"]').filter(function() 
            {
                    console.log(peaches);
                    console.log('inside var reqButEmpty assignment');
                    console.log(reqButEmpty);
                    return $.trim($(this).val()) === "";
            });
                console.log('just after var reqButEmpty assignment');
                    if(reqButEmpty.length>0)
                    {
                        console.log("inside .length");
                        console.log(this.length);
                        reqButEmpty.each(function() {
                            $('#hldErrMsg').append("Please fill in the " + this.name + "<br />"); 
                        });
                    }
                    return !reqButEmpty.length;
                });
        });

        </script>
```

Comment: Your closure is executing before the initial assignment of `reqButEmpty` completes.  So of course `reqButEmpty` will be undefined within the closure.

Comment: What's with all those alerts? `:)`

Comment: the undefined occurrs here: [var reqButEmpty = $('fieldset:visible').find('input[class*="-required"]')] the next alert does not work, even though it is before the closure.

Comment: just trying to narrow down the problem.  the 'peaches' is just to be sure the var is holding data and can output, then just checking i am in the function, then trying to output the contents of 'reqButEmpty', that alert [alert(reqButEmpty);] fails.  Tried testing in chrome debugger, i think something is not right with the .filter, but i don't know what.

Comment: @user - Consider that alerts are blocking! When working with asynchronous code, alerts can change how the code executes. Consider using console.info, console.log, and console.debug, warn, error, etc to avoid this problem. I'm not saying this is causing the problem, but it might be masking something else you won't be aware of until you *think* it's time to deploy.

Comment: @user1176783 That's an awful way to debug your code. Just set a break-point on line 1 and step through the code.

Comment: tried stepping thru code, on chrome and FF, shows nothing is going to var, resorted to placing the alerts to see if I could get more info.  I can remove the alerts if they are throwing anyone off.  Removing them on my end does not change the functioning or lack there of, of the code..

Comment: @user1176783 The debugger itself provides all the information you could need. The alerts don't provide anything in addition to that. *** Your code is incomplete. Could you post the entire code?

Comment: @user1176783 - I have added the code above.  The purpose of this is to add specialized form validation for a client.  So I working up to that, but got stuck with this issue.

Comment: @user1176783 I ran your code here - http://jsfiddle.net/jYBPY/ - and I didn't get any error... What exactly does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
$(function () {
    var $button = $( '#btnCatchReqFlds' );
    var $message = $( '#holdErrMsg' );

    $button.on( 'click', function () {
        var $reqButEmpty = $( 'input[class*="-required"]', 'fieldset:visible' ).filter(function () {
            return $.trim( $( this ).val() ) === '';
        });

        var html = $reqButEmpty.map(function () {
            return 'Please fill in the ' + this.name;
        }).get().join( '<br>' );

        $message.html( html );
    });
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/jYBPY/3/

Btw, you had a typo in your code - you wrote `"#hldErrMsg"` instead of `"#holdErrMsg"`.

Comment: Shoot me now - can't believe that - Thank you!  Could I ask another question?.  I need to do a check on drop-downs and want to add something like this, but of course the return won't work for a drop-down.  Do you know how I would incorporate this?: var dropdown_reqButEmpty = 
                 $('fieldset:visible')
                   .find('select[class*="-required"]')
                     .filter(function() {
                        return $.trim($(this).val()) === "";
                  });

Comment: @user1176783 It should work. `$(this).val()` will be an empty string if the `<option value="">` is selected... So, you can just select the SELECT elements using the same `reqButEmpty` object. `var $reqButEmpty = $( '[class*="-required"]', 'fieldset:visible' )...`